# how to implement ajax in Ruby on rails via jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

How do I pass a few of my form field(s) values to a controller usnig ajax/jquery?
For example, in php/jquery I do something like this:

```
    $("#test-btn").click(function(){
     var name=$("#name").val();
     var age=$("#age").val();
     $.post("insert.php",{name: name,age: age},
      function(data){
       $("#respone").html(data).hide().fadeIn(500);
      });
    });


//insert.php
<?php
 //insert values to database!
?>
```

How do I acheive a similar functionality in rails using ajax/jquery?

Comment: AJAX is part of Javascript, which is client-side and therefore server-side language independent. For the Javascript part, all you need to know is the URL and the names of the parameters to post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends.

You can do it the exact same way, which is suitable if you need to manipulate any data.

You can use Rails' UJS's `:remote => true` flag and do nothing; [here's a quick blog post on it](http://tech.thereq.com/post/18910961502/rails-3-using-form-remote-true-with-jquery-ujs). This is suitable for when you don't need to do anything other than submit, e.g., no manipulation.

Comment: could u please post me a sample code on how u do it. Because i'm stuck with this since a very long time not able to proceed! I would also like to know how u achieve server-side validation via ajax/jquery for the same.